# How can I use Google Maps API to import KML and click on polygons?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

Basically I have a KML file that has a TON of polygons to be mapped out. I need those polygons to be clickable in which I'd perform an ajax response.

I'm pretty lost, though. Can someone point me in the right direction? :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the polygon-array example that the Google Maps documentation refers to. It shows how to draw polygons, and how to respond to clicks on such polygons.

To view the example:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays.html

To view the source-code behind it:

view-source:http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays.html

Comment: That's cool and easy to understand. Can I integrate a KML file to generate these polygons and then add events like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.376259, 25.055542),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var Place = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'path-to-kml.kml'
    });

    Place.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(Place, 'click', function (event) {
        window.location.href = 'http://example.com'
    });  

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```